# Why does qmake put all object (.o) files to one directory?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Let's say I have a Qt application where I have two classes with the same name in two different namespaces:

```
namespace namespace1
{
    class SomeClass;
}

namespace namespace2
{
    class SomeClass;
}
```

and I have a project directory structure according to it:

```
-->src/
  -->namespace1/
    -->someclass.cpp
  -->namespace2/
    -->someclass.cpp
```

When I compile the application with qmake, it puts all object (.o) files to one directory - so it creates **someclass.o** file first and then it rewrites it with the second **someclass.o** - which is a name collision so it is bad.

Why does qmake not take into account the directory structure of the source files and why does it not create something like **namespace1_someclass.o** and **namespace2_someclass.o**?

Yes, I can put my classes to one directory and name them **namespace1_someclass.cpp** and **namespace2_someclass.cpp** and there will be no name collisions, but this causes little inconvenience while looking at the source files in the project explorer in Qt Creator because when there are lot of source files in the project, it is much less readable than if there was **the directory structure** which I can expand or collapse.

One more extreme is to have the directory structure like this:

```
-->src/
  -->namespace1/
    -->namespace1_someclass.cpp
  -->namespace2/
    -->namespace2_someclass.cpp
```

which solves name collision but it **redundantly duplicates** the namespace names - and therefore again less readable.

Why does qmake not have at least **an option to put the object files to the directory structure according to the source files**? Do creators of Qt not see that this is an important feature?

And one more thing - you could recommend me to use **cmake** tool instead of **qmake** but I see the use of cmake **much much much more difficult** than qmake and qmake does its job excellent for me so far - except object files placement.

Comment: I can only guess about what the authors of qmake were thinking; my guess is that they just didn't anticipate that anyone would have multiple .cpp files with the same name in the same project.  FWIW they are working on a replacement for qmake called qbs ... perhaps it does a better job (I haven't tried it myself so I don't know):  http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2012/02/15/introducing-qbs/

Answer (score 16):

You can actually put object files alongside source files by using:

`CONFIG += object_parallel_to_source`

or

`CONFIG += object_with_source`

depending on your qmake version.

*Source: https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake#Config_features*

Comment: Not sure why this does not have more upvotes. `CONFIG += object_parallel_to_source` on `Qt5` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on by default? Can anybody think of a possible problem or performance penalty of using this every time?

Comment: It works if the class does not inherits from QObject. If the class inherits from QObject, Qt still generates all the  moc_*.cpp files in the same place... Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you are trying to build, you may be able to use the `subdirs` template in qmake to do this. You'll need to put a project file in each of your `namespace` directories, and in this you can specify different output directories for your object files.

```
-->src/main.pro
  -->namespace1/n1.pro
    -->someclass.cpp
  -->namespace2/n2.pro
    -->someclass.cpp
```

`main.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS  = namespace1 namespace2
```

`n1.pro` and `n2.pro`:

```
include("../common.pri")
OBJECTS_DIR = $${PWD}
TARGET = some_target
TEMPLATE = some_qmake_template
```

`common.pri`: configurations common to both projects.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your fears that `CMake` might be too complicated: I have been working on projects using both build systems. While I agree that `qmake` is probably easier to begin with, `CMake` definitely has its merits, too:

- It makes out-of-source builds very easy. Just execute `cmake <Path to source>` in your build directory. This is great when your sources are on an NFS share, for example, and you want the object files to be placed on a local file system.
- Its support for finding additional libraries is very powerful. Lots of `FindXXX.cmake` files are already shipped with your `CMake` distribution, making the inclusion of "heavy" libraries such as `OpenCV` as easy as `FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)`.
- It even has out-of-the-box support for `Qt`. In fact, I use it for a larger software project where `Qt` is used for the GUI part. We decided on `CMake` because we required platform independence and multiple libraries which we could not easily add via `qmake`.

All in all, use the build system **you** are comfortable with (as long as your build system does not inhibit your software development).